# How to convert row to column Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have bellow json format

```
const datalist = [{"Week":"01","Apple":8,"Orange":1},
                  {"Week":"02","Orange":9,"Apple":1},
                  {"Week":"03","Apple":10,"Orange":0}];
```

i want to convert into bellow format

```
const datalist = [{"Food":"Apple","Week 1":8,"Week 2":1, "Week 3": 10, "Total" : 19},
                  {"Food":"Orange","Week 1":0,"Week 2":9, "Week 3": 0, "Total" :10 }];
```

i used bellow logic but im not able to get the correct result also the total

```
 const convert = toConvert => {
                const map = toConvert.reduce((r, {Week, Apple, Orange}) => {
                  if (r.has(Week))
                    r.set(Week, {...r.get(Week), [Apple]: Orange});
                 else
                     r.set(Week, {Week, [Apple]: Orange});
                  return r;
              }, new Map());
              return [...map.values()];
            };
            
            console.log(convert(datalist));
```

Comment: Off topic: you don't have any JSON - review what JSON actually is.   Makes no difference to the question, just terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through array of `fruits` like this:

```js
const datalist = [{"Week":"01","Apple":8,"Orange":1},
                  {"Week":"02","Orange":9,"Apple":1},
                  {"Week":"03","Apple":10,"Orange":0}];

const fruits = datalist.map(f => Object.keys(f).filter(k => k !== "Week"))[0];
let newData = fruits.map((f) => {
  let data = {};
  let total = 0;
  data['Food'] = f;
  datalist.forEach((d)=>{
    data[`Week ${parseInt(d['Week'])}`] = d[f];
    total += d[f];
  });
  data['Total'] = total;
  return data;
});
console.log(newData);
```